# Нужно ли тут тире?

Tags: пунктуация

И еще из того же текста: "На полянах и вдоль речки () масса красивейших цветов". Перед словом "масса" нужно тире или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необязательно, но, думаю, лучше его поставить.

Answer (score 0):

Тире поставить можно. Оно будет на месте пропущенного сказуемого.